# option.text() is vulnerable to xss in my example fiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss, html-sanitizing

Why am I getting the alert box in

```js
    $(function() {  
      $('#users').each(function() {  
        var select = $(this);  
        var option = select.children('option').first();  
        select.after(option.text());  
        select.hide();  
      });  
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="users" name="users">  
    <option value="bad">&lt;script&gt;alert(&#x27;xss&#x27;);&lt;/script&gt;</option>  
</select>
```

though I have the encoded version `(&lt;script&gt;alert(&#x27;xss&#x27;);&lt;/script&gt;)` in the option text ??

I am trying to prevent showing the alert because I have encoded html in the option text.Can someone tell me what am i missing?

https://jsfiddle.net/hf1fbhmg/

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**

Comment: Getting around the jsfiddle limitation by hidding a link inside a block of (non-existing) code is a no-no

Comment: I didn't know how to insert a link. Apologize.

Comment: @user3501278 — You don't need to insert a link. You need to put the relevant code in the question.

Comment: ... It's in the help section. The one you are forced to read when you make your first question

Comment: I tried to rephrase my question to avoid confusion. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have encoded html in the option text.

That doesn't matter because you are getting a text representation of it (with `text()`). (Even if you were getting an HTML representation, the rules for how browsers convert the text in the DOM back to HTML might give you unexpected results anyway).

You then use `select.after(that_text);`. If you pass a string that looks like HTML (which you are) to `after` then jQuery will treat it as HTML. You need to explicitly treat it as text.

For example:

```
select.after(
    jQuery("<span />").text(that_text)
);
```

Comment: @JeremyBanks — It has a bunch of things in it which I find surprising and/or badly documented… this isn't one of them though.

Comment: "Even if you were getting an HTML representation, the rules for how browsers convert the text in the DOM back to HTML might give you unexpected results anyway"  ->  how do i prevent this? that is what I am unable to figure it out.

Comment: @user3501278 — As I said, that's something that comes loaded with gotchas, so don't even try. Do what I recommended instead.

Comment: @user3501278 You should use `.html()` to get the HTML representation, that will include the encoding.

Comment: @user3501278 Basically, you should use the same function for reading and storing -- either read and write with `.html()` or read and write with `.text()`.

Comment: Why someone(who is trying to hack my dirty code)  thinks about using .html() instead of text() which is vulnerable? That is what confusing me.

Comment: @user3501278 — You are confusing what is safe to *read* data with and what is safe to *write* data with.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am confused over why it is showing alert box even though my option text is sanitized ? I asm assuming that browser will interpret any input as plain text after sanitization.

Comment: @user3501278 — Because, as I said, you read it as text (`<script>` etc) and then tell jQuery to treat that text as HTML. Sanitisation only applies at the point where you insert it into the page (which is the plain HTML before JS gets involved). What do you afterwards can desanitise it (which is exactly what you are doing).